# Match string starting with THIS until THAT Regex

Tags: python, regex

Here is my file content.

```
Whatever conent goes here
# --------------- POINT OF INTEREST BEGIN ------------------- #

<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="XMP Core 5.1.2">
    <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
        <rdf:Description rdf:about="" xmlns:xmp="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:exif="http://ns.adobe.com/exif/1.0/" xmp:ModifyDate="2014-03-06T12:39:48+05:00" exif:DateTimeOriginal="2014-03-05T18:26:01+05:00">
            <dc:creator>
                <rdf:Seq>
                    <rdf:li>Picasa</rdf:li>
                </rdf:Seq>
            </dc:creator>
        </rdf:Description>
    </rdf:RDF>
</x:xmpmeta>
# --------------- POINT OF INTEREST ENDS ------------------- #
Whatever content goes here
```

Here is what i am trying to achive. 
I want to match `<x:xmpmeta and` select the whole file path untill `</x:xmpeta>`
I am having hard time to translate the regex in the following form.

```
"Start from <x:xmpmeta and whatever comes after that including \r\n untill </x:xmpmeta>"
```

How can i translate it in Regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fairly simple, provided you don't have any additional `<x:xmpmeta>` elements nested within other `<x:xmpmeta>` elements:

`<x:xmpmeta[\w\W]*?</x:xmpmeta>`

The character set `[\w\W]` containing both the word character class and its negated character class is an easy way to match everything, including newlines.  You could actually replace it with any other character class along with its negated class, such as `[\s\S]`, if you wanted to for some reason.

The `?` is important to have after the `*` with a regex such as this, since if you had another `<x:xmpmeta></x:xmpmeta>` block later in the code, a single match would start with the first one, continue past the closing tag, grab everything in between, and only stop at the last instance of `</x:xmpmeta>`.

Comment: Thank  you \w\W was missing :)